# Nuance between « on dirait » and « il semblerait »

Tags: sens

> 1 : **On dirait** que nous avons été bernés par une ruse élaborée.
>
> 2 : **Il semblerait** que nous ayons été bernés par une ruse élaborée.

The 1st and 2nd sentences (in the conditional) convey more uncertainty than the 3rd. But do you detect any nuance between the first two? Perhaps, you are somewhat more certain of a situation when you use « on dirait » than when you do « il semblerait »?

> 3 : **Il semble** que nous ayons été bernés par une ruse élaborée.

---

Another point to consider: « on dirait » can be placed at the end, too, but what about the other two expressions?

> 4 : Nous avons été bernés par une ruse élaborée, **on dirait**.

Comment: Your forgot: `J'ai l'impression` and  `Je crois` if you want to have an exhaustive pov.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that the first two options differ in style but not in any significant way in meaning. I'd use #1 at home (everyday language) and be more comfortable using #2 at work (more formal).

Considering your other point, I don't see how you would place "il semble" or "il semblerait" at the end without changing the grammatical mood from subjunctive to indicative. "Nous avons été bernés par une ruse élaborée... il semble": possible, especially if you mark a pause, as if realizing what actually happened to you.

Note: I'm a native speaker but not a linguist.

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a pas la moindre différence en signfication dans les deux premières formes et je ne crois pas que l'on doive insister sur ce qui serait une plus grande propriété de « il semblerait » au vue que le verbe est spécifique au concept, bien que ce soit débâtable; disons que « il semblerait » est un peu plus formel.

Rejeter la clause à la fin de la phrase est une possibilité et elle sert les personnes qui se lancent à la hâte dans leurs assertions, en cela que ça leur permet de faire un commentaire sur ce qu'elles viennent de dire, de le qualifier exactement; l'effet est le même sur l'interlocuteur; néanmoins ce n'est pas de la langue très élégante même si acceptable et **seulement dans le cas de « on dirait » fait-on ce rejet couramment**. Lorsqu'il s'agit de « Il semblerait » un petit ajustement est nécessaire pour que le rejet soit ressenti par l'interlocuteur comme de la langue habituelle: il ne faut plus utiliser « il semblerait» mais « il me semble ».